# Vírus introduzido numa pergunta?

Tags: suporte, conteúdo

Queria sugerir adicionar segurança nas respostas e perguntas quanto se fala a respeito de código adicionado. Duma uma certa forma esquisita o meu antivírus Avast reclama sempre de um trojan na seguinte pergunta:

[O que o código abaixo (escrito por um cracker) faz?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8721/o-que-o-codigo-abaixo-escrito-por-um-cracker-faz/)

Aviso: Não recomendo entrar no link se não tiver antivírus instalado.

A minha duvida será a seguinte será que o meu antivírus reconhece o código php mesmo não estando em execução e como tal dá a alerta ou será que o código executa mesmo estando só na pergunta?

Comment: O código **não** executa (abrir o link é seguro). O antivirus está provavelmente analisando todo o trafego de rede e se deparando com o código php que já está no seu banco de dados de ameaças. Não acho que exista coisa alguma que o site possa fazer quanto a isso.

Comment: É muito estranho porque ele queixa-se se for ver ao pormenor de um gzip passado pelo processo chrome.exe, continuo a achar que é algo que vale a pena ser analisado.

Comment: @CMPSoares Eu concordo que provavelmente o problema é com seu antivirus, e não com o site. Experimente algumas perguntas similares no security.SE ([exemplo](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/33664/6939)) - onde esse tipo de pergunta é razoavalmente comum - e veja se seu antivirus acusa alguma coisa. (P.S. Caso não saiba, o StackExchange é desenvolvido em .Net, não PHP, então a chance de um código PHP malicioso infectar o site é virtualmente nula)

Comment: Fiz a pergunta no Meta do SO internacional (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252749/virus-introduced-in-a-question) onde a discussão está bastante fugosa. Conclusão parece ser que o meu antivirus é um pouco paranoid!

Comment: Você chegou a ler [esse link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100817/177950) dentre os comentários na pergunta do MSE? Parece que não é a primeira vez que o Avast confunde a foto do tigre com a coisa real... O usuário que achou o problema anterior [abriu um ticket no Avast](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/100838/177950) e, pouco depois, uma funcionária do Avast [respondeu](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/101013/177950) anunciando que as definições de vírus foram atualizadas pra lidar com esse falso positivo. Parece se tratar do mesmo problema então, ou seja - é problema no Avast, não no SE...

Comment: (mas o caso do beacon, confesso que me pegou de surpresa - achei que tinha lido que o SE proibia incluir imagens de domínios externos... Mas vejo agora que não é bem assim)

Comment: @mgibsonbr eu vi depois... A mim estava constantemente a aparecer... Tive de adicionar a lista seguro a combinação de links do SO ( \*.stackoverflow.\*) se não dava em doido!

E sim eu também pensava que não dava mas depois de experimentar por causa desta questão fiquei contente até porque é bastante pratico! E até criei [este post](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14354/como-faco-para-adicionar-analise-em-tempo-real-das-visualizacoes-nas-minhas-perg/14355#14355).

Comment: @mgibson tanto que o beacon do apps é um da lista de bloqueio da minha máquina, assim como Analytics, like do facebook e mais um monte de trackers. Até alguns "JS famosos" eu redireciono do google pra uma URL minha com cópia, para evitar rastreio. Mas não chega a ser paranóia, é apenas "pra não perder o costume" ;)

Comment: @Bacco Como fazes isso?

Comment: @CMPSoares parte eu bloqueio no browser mesmo (O Opera 12 tem um filtro razoável built-in), algumas coisas pelo arquivo `hosts` do windows.

Comment: ah já cheguei a ver esse filtro mas eu até não me importo de dar informação desde que não seja de forma abusiva...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo o [Meta do StackOverflow principal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252749/virus-introduced-in-a-question) não existe perigo algum. O que aparenta acontecer é que o Anti-vírus reconhece o código e acaba por ser um pouco paranóico e desta forma gerar um falso-positivo.

Como a SO só permite uma quantidade limitada de tags html a serem utilizadas a probabilidade de se conseguir introduzir um vírus no mesmo é mínima.

Comment: É bem improvável que se consiga injetar algum código malicioso no StackExchange como um todo. Tendo em vista que os sites possuem anos e anos online e já devem ter tratado todas as brechas de segurança, até porque o maior site deles é de programação, e os próprios programadores apontariam estes tipos de erros. Em outras palavras, pode ficar tranquilo que é mais fácil "pegar virus" abrindo o Facebook do que aqui. :)